# To "affect change"

Tags: word-usage

I am curious whether the following use of the word "affect" is legitimate:

> I feel this is the best way I can affect positive change in this country.

I am trying to avoid using "enact change" because "enact" gives me a connotation of actually getting something done. (If I enact legislation, I have put it into effect.) Is this legitimate?

Comment: It sounds slightly formal to me, but it is used correctly and sounds natural in this sentence.

Comment: No. It's wrong! The word is effect: "Cause (something) to happen; bring about." https://www.lexico.com/definition/effect

Comment: If you are trying to avoid that connotation perhaps you should say, "...this is the best way I can contribute to bringing about positive change..."

Comment: As per a previous comment, it needs to be **effect**, not **affect**. That aside, if the connotation is *not* getting something done (making a change), then what is it?

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't understand your question.

Comment: @jeremy909 You said this: "'enact' gives me a connotation of actually getting something done." But if you *effect change* that means that you bring about change. Or, in parallel language, "get change done." As far as I can tell, there is no difference. Both talk about putting something in place. Where do you see a difference?

Comment: @JasonBassford "Effect change" sounds to me like I contribute to the progress of certain change. Is that not correct?

Comment: @jeremy909 To *effect* change, at least in my mind, is to cause change to happen, to bring it about. By contributing to it, you alter it or help to have it altered.